# How can I use conditional formatting to check for changes between two worksheets?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements

In both sheets, in column A I have amounts. In another column, let's say E, I have account numbers. The amounts relate to the account numbers. For example, $50 in account 1234567. I've managed to get some conditional formatting working on a sheet so it looks up the previous days sheet and highlights any change in each amount.

But here's where I've run into a problem. Today after downloading today's spreadsheet, there are new account numbers that have been added which weren't in yesterday's sheet. So when I run `=A1<>sheet1!A1`, as soon as it gets to an account number it doesn't recognise, the function no longer works and ends up highlighting loads of cells.

Is there a way to first verify which payments are with which account number, and then use conditional formatting to highlight any changes? Because at the moment, a new account number is where a different account number is on the old spreadsheet, and this is completely messing the conditional formatting up from this point in the sheet onwards.

I hope I've explained this well enough. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using vlookup() in your formatting? This could tell you if the account number appears and with the same value. But it would not tell you if addition accounts appear.

Comment: I have managed to highlight any different account numbers using COUNTIF. However, I need to be able to highlight any amounts in column A a different colour IF they don't align with the original account number. For example, here is sheet 1: https://i.imgur.com/dA2Q6BN.png. And sheet 2: https://i.imgur.com/JRNELnh.png - For example, if the first account number equals anything other than "1.00" I need to be able to highlight the new amount in sheet2. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a solution following some Best Practices.
I expect you appreciate my answer.
Please rate this session accordingly and leave me any comments you have!
In case I can contribute for your projects please contact me.

So let's create a clear viewable example EXCEL workbook.
For this case I recommend you to:

- Use this clear formula:

  `=VLOOKUP([@[Acc Number]],tabBASE,2,FALSE)`
- Always name cell intervals, sheets, Table Objects, with easily unmistakable identifiable name.
- In this case I renamed Sheet1 to "tabBase" where the older Account List exists.
- In this case I renamed Sheet2 to "tabNewer" where we compare the New Account List to the older one.
- When possible I usually insert a Table Object in my data tables (ribbon:Insert\Table). In this way you get automatic human readable column naming.
- For clarity I usually rename the Table Object data cell range to the same sheet name.
- When possible use VLOOKUP() function instead INDEX MATCH combination.
- VLOOKUP() it's clear to understand and is adequate for 99% of these kind of requirement.
- VLOOKUP() looks to match the value in [tabNewer][Acc Number] column to the first column on [tabBase].
- Don't forget that the key column to lookup must be the first, leftmost, on the lookup list table.
- Don't forget to add to VLOOKUP() the 4th argument "FALSE", to ensure you get the exact match or "N/A" not available is [tabNewer][Acc Number] not on the list.

[IMAGE:Sheet1 Base Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cNbK.png)

[IMAGE:Sheet2 Newer Table Compare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8RLG.png)

[IMAGE:Conditional Formating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHj16.png)